# How can I delete rows that containing a specific character

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to do the delete rows that containing a specific character

This is an example of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to keep IDs which does not have `B` in them
input

```
IDs
WW-111
WW-112
WW2_111B
WW2_112B
WW_1234
2210B
2222B
```

I'm looking for output as this

```
IDs
WW-111
WW-112
WW_1234
```

What is the right approach to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *base* you can use `grepl` and negate the hits of `B` like:

```
x[!grepl("B", x)]
[1] "WW-111"  "WW-112"  "WW_1234"
```

Data:

```
x  <- c("WW-111","WW-112","WW2_111B","WW2_112B","WW_1234","2210B","2222B")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep things simple, you can use `stringr::str_detect`:

```
x <- c("A", "AB", "BB", "CC", "D", "DBD")
x[!stringr::str_detect(x, "B")]
```

**Output**

```
"A"  "CC" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `^[^B]+$`

Breaking it down, this means

```
^         start of the string
 [^B]     any character except those in the brackets
     +    at least one of the previous characters
      $   end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the `invert` and `value` arguments in `grep`

```
grep("B$", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "WW-111"  "WW-112"  "WW_1234"
```

#### data

```
x  <- c("WW-111","WW-112","WW2_111B","WW2_112B","WW_1234","2210B","2222B")
```

Answer (score 0):

An amateur method would be:

Accept strings->accept or define character that shouldnt be in string->run loop checking each character of string, take a counter variable, if variable =0, print string.